# deploy Django site on Netlify

Tags: django, netlify

I'm trying to upload my full-stack website, done with Django and React on Netlify.
I have tried various ways and searched for different tutorials, but unfortunately I did not find them useful ...

Many recommend using cactus to launch their own applications consisting of python, but I don't think it can work with Django, does anyone know how to do it or give me some advice? Thanks

*note: netlify is only for "static" websites, so how can I make my Django application "static"?*

Answer (score 1):

Netlify is not really the match made in heaven for Django, I think you should give [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/working-with-django) a go, which supports Django out-of-the-box.

If you do want to use Netflify and are ready to resign from the Django's backend features (built-in database, admin panel etc are not going to work after you make a static export), Cactus does work with Django. You could also try [django-distill](https://jamstack.org/generators/django-distill/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not fully complete...